# Azure Devops: check in code changes, but do not change task state?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using TFS on Azure DevOps for source control. Every time, after I check in a code change, the task state will automatically changed to "close". I remember there is a way to prevent the state from changing, say keeping it as 'Active'. But could not find where to set this.

Anyone knows?

thanks

Comment: Are you using visual studio by any chance? If not, what's your coding IDE?

Comment: yes, Visual studio.

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: 2019 community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting in Visual Studio is to resolve work items on check in.

To change this behaviour, go to `Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` and uncheck the box marked `Resolve associated work items on check-in`

[image]